# Airbnb alternative that doesn't require ID verification

Tags: online-resources, accommodation, airbnb

Since Airbnb needs its users to verify their ID by uploading a photo of their driver's license or passport, I'm in search for another service quite like Airbnb, but without this way of approving one's identity.

Can you recommend me some?

Comment: It doesn't sound like a good idea to run such a service. Alternatives are wimdu and 9flats. They probably also require you to identify yourself.

Comment: @MastaBaba I agree but it is hard for me to trust my IDs to such services as Airbnb

Comment: It works the other way, it is hard for Airbnb to trust you without an ID!

Comment: @MichaelHampton of course, trust issues over internets are hard.

Comment: I'm surprised this needs to be said: Very few individuals will be willing to rent out their place to someone who has not been verified beforehand. If you don't want to verify yourself, you are not too likely to find a place to stay through services where the majority does verify itself.

Comment: I think you can consider Airbnb successful and large enough that you can be pretty sure their business model of brokering lodging is far more profitable than selling your personal data and losing everyone's trust.

Comment: Craigslist would probably list a few places that don't require ID

Comment: "Craigslist would probably list a few places that don't require ID", and that rent by the hour.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Why? They have my credit card details and can charge me for any damage or hand the details to the police if it is a criminal affair. So why do they need the ID to have trust?

Comment: @MastaBaba Why? They have my credit card details and can charge me for any damage or hand the details to the police if it is a criminal affair. So why do they need the ID to have trust?

Comment: @OleTange The host does not have your cc details. They have to hope that any damage you cause will be paid for by airbnb, who has the renter's cc details. Just being aware of a cc is no guarantee that the person says they are who they say they are. Also being aware, as a host, that the renter has verifiably tied themselves to an identifiable ID means the risk of a bogus renter is smaller.

Comment: @MastaBaba Why would you be in a better position if you know who the renter is? Isn't the goal to have the renter pay for the damage? Then you really do not need to know who they are, as long as you can get money from them.

Comment: @OleTange If you know more about a person, you can establish a higher level of trust. If the host is renting out a property that's specifically on the market to be rented out, making sure damage is paid is probably his primary concern. If the host is renting out his own house, or a room in his own house, higher levels of trust are better, as just getting damages paid is meaningless if the renter destroys items that are of personal importance. But, either way, this might not be how you perceive things, it seems this is how many hosts perceive things.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You have several options:

1. Use Airbnb without a verified ID. While a lot of hosts require one explicitly, there are still some that don't ask for it. I've tested it myself by registering a brand new user profile - it's still possible to contact hosts and make reservations without an ID scan (or even a photo).
2. Use an online service that doesn't verify IDs, such as [VRBO](http://www.vrbo.com/) or [9flats](http://www.9flats.com/).
3. Go the old-fashioned way and use a regular classifieds website, such as [Craigslist](http://craigslist.org). Countries outside the US usually have their own classifieds websites, so you'd have to do a bit of research for each region you're planning to visit.

Answer (score 2):

[Booking.com](https://join.booking.com/) and [Agoda](https://www.agoda.com/homes) also seem to do renting without ID verification.

So now the list is [VRBO](https://www.vrbo.com/) [9flats](https://www.9flats.com/) [Booking.com](https://join.booking.com/) and [Agoda](https://www.agoda.com/homes).

Comment: I've used booking.com quite frequently, it's a pretty nice and straightforward service, I have very good experiences with it, however it (and agoda too i think) is primarily for booking things like hotels and hostels, i.e. the identity verification just happens on-location instead of through the service (which is to be honest much preferable anyways imo.)